# How to export function from class components? REACT-NATIVE

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-studio

I have a class component and I need to pass one of its function to the drawer and use it, but don't know if it's possible:

```js
class Edit_note extends Component { 
  save_changes = async() => {
    let clear_content = this.state.content.replace(/&nbsp;/g,""); //replace al &nbsp; 
    try {
      const data = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem("data"));
      const index_to_find = this.array_notes.findIndex(obj => obj.note_number === this.note[0].note_number); 
      
      const edited_note = this.note.map((note) => {
        note.content = clear_content;
        return {...note}
      });
         
      this.array_notes.splice(index_to_find, 1, edited_note[0]);
      data.array_notes = this.array_notes; 
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data));
    } catch(error) {
      alert(error);
    } 
  }
    
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Text>hi</Text>
      </>
    ); 
  }  
}
    
export default Edit_note;
```

this is my class component, and I want to export the function save_changes and use it in the header of edit note, put it in the icon

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import { Feather } from '@expo/vector-icons'; 
    
class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <View style ={{backgroundColor: "white", flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center"}}>
          <View>
            <Text style = {{color: "black", fontSize: 30, marginLeft: -20}}>{this.props.title}</Text>
          </View>
          <Feather name="check-square" size={24} color = "black" />
        </View>
      </>
    );
  }
}
    
export default Header;
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that. Only way is to extract `save_changes` out of the class as a utility, export it and use it where ever u need passing the right parameters.

In the file where you have your class component, make the following changes:

```
 export const save_changes = async(<Pass the parameter here>) => {
    
    let clear_content = this.state.content.replace(/&nbsp;/g,""); //replace al &nbsp; 

    try {
    
        const data = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem("data"));
        const index_to_find = this.array_notes.findIndex(obj => obj.note_number === this.note[0].note_number); 
   
        const edited_note = this.note.map((note) => {
            note.content = clear_content;
            return {...note}
        });
   
        this.array_notes.splice(index_to_find, 1, edited_note[0]);
        data.array_notes = this.array_notes;
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data));
     
    }catch(error) {
        alert(error);
    }

}    

class Edit_note extends Component { 



render() {

    return (
        <>
           <Text>hi</Text>
        </>
    );

}

}

 export default Edit_note;
```

Now you can import the `save_changes` function anywhere from this file

Comment: and how I do that?

Comment: mmm, this way I cant use the varibles inside the class right?

Comment: For that, you need to return the data from your function and set it inside the class component. its just how you write the code.

Answer (score 0):

To export a function from your component, you need it to be `public static`, and remove all usage of `this` within the function. The `public` word means that the function can be accessed from outside the component, with `Edit_note.save_changes()`. The keyword `static` is used to make the function independant of the component's instance.

To import the data you need from your instance, you can pass them as parameters in your function `save_changes`.

As a result, you should have something like this:

```js
  public static async save_changes (content, array_notes, note) {
    let clear_content = content.replace(/&nbsp;/g,""); //replace al &nbsp; 
    try {
      const data = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem("data"));
      const index_to_find = array_notes.findIndex(obj => obj.note_number === note[0].note_number); 
      
      const edited_note = note.map((note) => {
        note.content = clear_content;
        return {...note}
      });
         
      array_notes.splice(index_to_find, 1, edited_note[0]);
      data.array_notes = array_notes; 
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data));
    } catch(error) {
      alert(error);
    } 
  }
```

And then, you can call this function in any other component with `Edit_note.save_changes()`, as long as the component `Edit-note` is imported as well at the top lines of the component.

Comment: Would be a better approach if the class is not a React Component. Otherwise why not to create a simple class and instantiate it where ever needed and call the function ?